# Uncountable noun examples

Tags: grammatical-number

We were taught at school that if we want to make something plural, we should add "s" at the end. Later on, I learned that there are uncountable nouns. Not so much familiar with it. Can you please give some examples?

Comment: Offhand I can just give you one: furniture

Answer (score 1):

Uncountable nouns are substances, concepts etc that we cannot divide into separate elements. We cannot count them.

For example,

tea

sugar
water
air
rice
knowledge
beauty
anger
fear
love
money
research
safety
evidence

Lets look at some sentence examples.
We can use some and any with uncountable nouns:

-I've got some money

-Have you got any rice?

Please see links for further explanation

https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/nouns-uncountable-list.htm

Comment: +1, but note that almost all of those words are also sometimes countable, with well-attested plurals. (I don't think I've ever heard *rices*, *knowledges*, *angers*, or *evidences*, but the rest are unexceptionable.)

Comment: @ruakh *Evidences* does exist, but the form is [either obsolete, obsolescent, or very specialised](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/118730/18696).