# verb conjugation after uncountable noun (evidence)

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, uncountable-nouns

Evidence is supposed to be uncountable, though the form evidences is also accepted, as already discussed in the topic below: [Is "evidence" countable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118727/is-evidence-countable)

We usually treat uncountable nouns as singular, right? So it should it be:

"evidence supports the associations..." correct?

However, I often come across this form too: "evidence support the…"

So it leaves me unsure as to what sounds better for an academic paper: "evidence supports" or "evidence support"?

Comment: You will often come across incorrect English. The trick is to recognise it when you do, and you seem to have this "well in hand".

Answer (score 3):

As @Mick said in comments :

> You will often come across incorrect English. The trick is to recognise it when you do, and you seem to have this "well in hand".

The third-party singular form (*evidence supports*) is correct.

The third-party plural form (*evidence support*) is incorrect.

These ngrams might help :

- [Evidence support(s)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=evidence+support%2Cevidence+supports&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cevidence%20support%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevidence%20supports%3B%2Cc0)
- [Evidence show(s)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=evidence+show%2C+evidence+shows&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cevidence%20show%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevidence%20shows%3B%2Cc0)

*Note that the plural form is included in the singular form, but the difference still is way too big.*

Comment: @Mick I hope you don't mind my plagiarism

Comment: Note that many of the *evidence support* instances are actually correct, as they are part of questions, e.g., *Does the **evidence support** the conclusion?* Third-person singular verbs generally work that way: *Does the train **run** at night?* *No, the train **runs** only during the day.*

Answer (score 2):

*Evidence* is usually a collective noncountable, and if the Ngram viewer is to be believed, usage with a plural verb is vanishingly rare. A reasonable time spent in the Ngram viewer sifted one only example from the false drops.  From [*The Other Side of Justice*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2TlaBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT171&dq=%22the%20evidence%20are%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX98nThNHQAhXKOyYKHVziByM4ChDoAQhTMAk#v=onepage&q=%22the%20evidence%20are%22&f=false) by L Griggs:

> You should remember that opening statements, however, are not evidence.  **The evidence are** from the witnesses.

But *evidence* is not always noncountable. The *OED* attests to the plural *evidences* in the context of Christianity, particularly as to the support for a person's salvation, although it appears in other contexts as well, from particular claims like the resurrection of Christ to the religion in general.

This usage is becoming rare, if the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=evidences%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cevidences%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bevidences%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bevidences%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bevidences%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bevidences%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bevidences%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bevidences%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bevidences%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bevidences%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bevidences%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bevidences%20on%3B%2Cc0) viewer is to be believed, with current usage reduced by more than an order of magnitude from its most popular, but it is by no means extinct, as the following cites show.

From [*Count Your Blessings*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0CZV6AB_dRUC&pg=PA17&dq=%22evidences%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcxc___dDQAhXJ4iYKHTvHDG04UBDoAQgaMAA#v=onepage&q=%22evidences%20of%22&f=false) (1961) by J R Rice

> So all the lovingkindness [sic], all the tender mercy which comes to one in this life are simply the **evidences** of the loving provision of God.

From [***Evidences*** of the Flood](https://books.google.com/books?id=FhUIfPj7Zt4C&pg=PA4&dq=%22evidences%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8hYbC-9DQAhVBKCYKHXmJAFgQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22evidences%20of%22&f=false) (1972) by W W Greenman:

> Now, as the Flood covered all the earth, we might well expect to find marks and **evidences** of it in many parts of the earth,....

The law also uses the plural, as opposed to the collective singular as in *the body of evidence*, particularly when the evidence referred to is called out by type:

From [*Cases of Contested Elections in Congress*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bQ8EfoaTBLsC&pg=PA134&dq=%22evidences%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2kKWZ99DQAhUCSyYKHTX0B0c4PBDoAQggMAE#v=onepage&q=%22evidences%20on%22&f=false): From the Year 1789 to 1834, Inclusive a report from the Committee on Elections issued by the House of Representataives of the United States Congress in 1834:

> It is incumbent on a person contesting the election of a sitting
>   member, to be prepared, *within a reasonable time*, to exhibit, in legal
>   form, the **evidences** on which he intends to rely in support of the
>   allegations contained in his petition.

Italics in the original. This passage immediately precedes the discussion of the types of evidence to be considered in a particular contested election, namely "depositions", "papers", "land lists", and "lists of voters"

From a more recent era, the [journal](https://books.google.com/books?id=CyVKVe5j1YYC&q=%22evidences%20of%22&dq=%22evidences%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjaseCc-tDQAhUBhiYKHcAwAc8Q6AEIMzAE) of the Illinois House of Representatives for 1989:

> ... to assure the repayment of bonds, notes, or other **evidences** of indebtedness.

Occasionally, the plural is used in scientific literature, an example from *Indians and Archaeology of Missouri, Revised Edition* (1983) by C H and E F Chapman:

> There are several means by which the archaeologist can approach the
>   problems of interpreting and explaining the **evidences** of the past
>   when no written records exist.

I have avoided citing usage from sources that I felt may have been translations or where the authors might not have been native speakers.

Comment: The second part of this answer is probably just as relevant to the linked question, if you want to post an answer there.