# Another evidence

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality

My son wrote:

> Another evidence of spring is the blooming flowers.

I want to explain why this is wrong but I can’t. My best attempt is that it feels wrong. I want to correct it as:

> Another piece of evidence is that you can find blooming flowers.

But that feels clumsy.

Why is what my son wrote wrong, or not wrong?

What is the most natural way to write it?

Comment: In that context it's idiomatic, if perhaps a hair informal.  But in general use "evidence" is uncountable and would not accept "another".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I want to explain why this is wrong but I can’t.

This is because *evidence* is a non-count noun, so you can't talk about "an evidence" or "another evidence".

This was previously addressed in the question, "[Is 'evidence' countable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118727/is-evidence-countable)"

You could talk about "more evidence" or "further evidence" to avoid the wordier (but just as correct) "another piece of evidence".

Comment: Another idiomatic replacement in this context would be 'another *sign* of spring'.