# is opportunity countable or non-countable?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I want to use the phrase "plenty of opportunities" in my essay, but I'm not sure whether opportunity is countable or not. Some people say that the phrase "plenty of opportunity" is acceptable, some say "a lot of opportunities". So which version is the most accurate?

Comment: Both are grammatical. Which is more accurate depends on what you want to express (which you haven’t told us).

Comment: If they are single occasions when you have the chance to do something, the word is countable.

Comment: Please let us know the rest of your sentence :)

Comment: You can have many job opportunities in life (countable). But if personified, Opportunity knocks (uncountable).

Answer (score 3):

Almost any uncountable word can be countable.

I can talk of cheese and cheeses (Cheddar and Wensleydale); of bread and breads (white and soda bread); even water and waters (pond water; sea water; drinking water). I can have a number of wines in the cellar. *Opportunity* is like this: many opportunities can arise to do something, in which case you have a lot of opportunity. When talking of *opportunities* each individual occasion is considered; but together they make a lot of opportunity.

Which you use, *opportunities* or *opportunity,* depends on whether you want to focus on each individual occasion you might do something, or the concept of being able to do it.

Some really abstract concepts are not easily made countable: [*evidence*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118727/is-evidence-countable) and *information* come to mind.

Many countable words can be uncountable: you can have buildings built of brick.

Comment: The information in the answer reveals several evidences of careful and exhaustive thought. I like it. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/evidence_1

Comment: In sum, the answer to the OP's headline question is *yes.*